# Returning or not a field postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have this tables:

timelines

```
id | post_id | group_id
```

post_views

```
id | post_id | user_id
```

My query is like:

```
SELECT distinct on (t.post_id) post_id, t.group_id, t.id, t.created_at
FROM timelines t  join post_views pv USING(post_id)
WHERE t.group_id IN (1, 2, 78)
```

It's "working", but I need to get other field named 'seen', and that field will receive true if has t.post_id = pv.post_id AND user_id = 100, or else return false or NULL

I can't do the `WHERE` in `JOIN` clause.

Thanks

---

Example:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m2HdHrZD5fY98tpGa1Eqsw/0

Guys, I made the example above to help you to help me :D

Comment: Just add the expression `t.post_id = pv.post_id AND user_id = 100` to your select list.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Answer (score 0):

You want `case` expression ? :

```
SELECT distinct on (t.post_id) post_id, t.group_id, t.id, t.created_at,
       (CASE WHEN t.post_id IN (1, 2, 78) AND user_id = 100 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS seen
FROM timelines t  join 
     post_views pv 
     USING(post_id)
WHERE t.group_id IN (1, 2, 78);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake: `will receive true if has post_id = (1,2,78) AND user_id = 100`!! pv.post_id = t.post_id. But is strange, because is return false when I have the same post_id and the user_id = 100

Comment: `ID | post_id | user_id 
47      44        100`

And this return false

Comment: You don't actually need a case, `t.post_id IN (1, 2, 78) AND user_id = 100` would be enough to return a boolean value

Answer (score 0):

You may think that your code is working, but you should be using `order by` with `distinct on`.  With the `order by`, you can put the user you want at the top, and then:

```
SELECT distinct on (post_id) post_id, t.group_id, t.id, t.created_at,
       (p.user_id = 100) as user_100_flag
FROM timelines t join
     post_views pv 
     using (post_id)
WHERE t.group_id IN (1, 2, 78)
ORDER BY post_id, (p.user_id = 100)::int desc;
```

Comment: Hm.. I understand what you do, but does not work :/ I made a example here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m2HdHrZD5fY98tpGa1Eqsw/0 Thx